# SQL Server : Remote Table insert fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is my setting: within my schema I have a stored procedure (shown below) which will insert a dummy row (for testing) into a remote table. The table `MY_REMOTE_TABLE` is a synonym pointing to the correct remote table.

I can successfully query it like

```
SELECT * FROM MY_REMOTE_TABLE;
```

on my local system. This does work.

So for testing I created the procedure with a dummy test value in it, which should be inserted into the remote table if the row is new to the remote table. Hint: the remote table is empty at the time of insertion, so it really should perform the insert.

But it always fails giving me a return value of -6. I have no clue what -6 stands for or even what the error could be. All I have is -6 and I know that nothing will be inserted into the remote table. Interestingly when I copy the insert statement to the remote server, replace the synonym with the real table name on the remote machine and execute, it works all fine.

So I'm really lost here seeking for your help!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_Procedure]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION 

       -- LEFT JOIN AND WHERE NULL WILL ONLY FIND NEW RECORDS -> THEREFORE INSERT INTO TARGET REMOTE TABLE
       INSERT INTO MY_REMOTE_TABLE
         (--id is not needed because it's an IDENTITY column
          user_id, 
          customer_id, 
          my_value, year, 
          Import_Date, Import_By, Change_Date,  Change_By)
          SELECT 
              Source.user_id, 
              Source.customer_id, 
              Source.my_value, 
              Source.year, 
              Source.Import_Date,
              Source.Import_By,
              Source.Change_Date, 
              Source.Change_By
           FROM 
              (SELECT 
                   null as id, 
                   126616 as user_id, 
                   17 as customer_id, 
                   0 as my_value, 
                   2012 as year, 
                   GETDATE() AS Import_Date, 
                   'test' AS Import_By, 
                   GETDATE() AS Change_Date, 
                   'test' AS Change_By) AS Source
           LEFT JOIN
               MY_REMOTE_TABLE AS Target ON Target.id = Source.id
                                         AND Target.user_id = Source.user_id
                                         AND Target.customer_id = Source.customer_id
                                         AND Target.year = Source.year
           WHERE
      Target.id IS NULL; -- BECAUSE OF LEFT JOIN NEW RECORDS WILL BE NULL, SO WE ONLY SELECT THEM FOR THE INSERT !!!

    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0 AND XACT_STATE() = 1)
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0AND XACT_STATE() = -1)     
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END CATCH;
END
```

another question related to this one. if my insert would violate an FK constraint on my remote table, how could I manage to promote the error message from the remote DB server to my local procedure to capture it?

Comment: I have a little more info. I printed out the ERROR_* properties. The error I get is 7395: Unable to start a nested transaction for OLE DB provider “SQLNCLI10″ for linked server “MyLinkedServer”. A nested transaction was required because the XACT_ABORT option was set to OFF. No clue what to do about this one... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188792.aspx

Short version:

> XACT_ABORT must be set ON for data modification statements in an
>   implicit or explicit transaction against most OLE DB providers,
>   including SQL Server. The only case where this option is not required
>   is if the provider supports nested transactions.

So insert a `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the start of the stored procedure.